# How does Spark's sort shuffle work?

Tags: apache-spark

From https://0x0fff.com/spark-architecture-shuffle/ I know that the default way of shuffeling in Spark is sort shuffle. However the description was not step-by-step enough to be clear for me. How does it work?

What I understand is that each mapper writes into exactly one `AppendOnlyMap` (*What are the keys?*), which is sorted (and spilled - *why spilled?*) into potentially multiple... *what exactly?*... then somehow written in some indexed (*what exactly is indexed by what with what key?*) file. I think the idea in the end is that all those sorted-and-indexed files are brought with this Min Heap Merge together to have only one big file per reduces.

As one can see - there are more wholes (things I don't understand) than Swiss cheese (things I do understand)...